# passing list from R to sql query

Tags: sql, list, vector

I am having a variable securities generated from tickers data frame

```
securities=tickers$ticker%>%setNames(tickers$country)
```

I am further passing them to an sql query which filters data by

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
WHERE id in :securities
```

I have a function getData(sql_query,params) which runs the query

How should I pass the securities list to the sql query from R